# Hibernate does too much joins for a single query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an airport database that I downloaded from the mysql site (I also uploaded a photo of it here) and I made all its settings in the spring boot program, but when I want to run a simple query `select f from Flight`, hibernate does a lot of strange joins and it doesn't end and the outOfMemory error is shown. In the following output, a part of hibernate queries are placed, which are not all of them, and in the middle of the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` is shown, and the program is terminated.

I had two questions:

First of all, what is the reason for all these joins?

Second, what is the way to prevent it?

[All models classes(with hibernate mappings)](https://mega.nz/folder/oxFzDKST#Jhy6zpBtZARmuZQ9QtWr5w)-you dont need to see the view folder.

EER photo:

[image]

output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        flight0_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_,
        flight0_.airline_id as airline_4_9_,
        flight0_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_,
        flight0_.arrival as arrival2_9_,
        flight0_.departure as departur3_9_,
        flight0_.from as from6_9_,
        flight0_.flightno as flightno7_9_,
        flight0_.to as to8_9_ 
    from
        flight flight0_ 
    order by
        flight0_.departure asc limit ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airline0_.airline_id as airline_1_0_0_,
        airline0_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_0_,
        airline0_.base_airport as base_air4_0_0_,
        airline0_.iata as iata3_0_0_,
        airport1_.airport_id as airport_1_3_1_,
        airport1_.iata as iata2_3_1_,
        airport1_.icao as icao3_3_1_,
        airport1_.name as name4_3_1_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_2_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.city as city2_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.country as country3_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.geolocation as geolocat4_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.latitude as latitude5_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.longitude as longitud6_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.name as name7_4_3_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_4_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_5_,
        airportrea3_.hops as hops2_5_5_ 
    from
        airline airline0_ 
    left outer join
        airport airport1_ 
            on airline0_.base_airport=airport1_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_geo airportgeo2_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportgeo2_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_reachable airportrea3_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportrea3_.airport_id 
    where
        airline0_.airline_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airplane0_.airplane_id as airplane1_1_0_,
        airplane0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_0_,
        airplane0_.type_id as type_id4_1_0_,
        airplane0_.capacity as capacity3_1_0_,
        airplanety1_.type_id as type_id1_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.description as descript2_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.identifier as identifi3_2_1_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flights2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flights2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flights2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flights2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flights2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flights2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        airline3_.airline_id as airline_1_0_4_,
        airline3_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_4_,
        airline3_.base_airport as base_air4_0_4_,
        airline3_.iata as iata3_0_4_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_6_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_6_,
        bookings4_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_6_,
        bookings4_.price as price2_7_6_,
        bookings4_.seat as seat3_7_6_,
        airport5_.airport_id as airport_1_3_7_,
        airport5_.iata as iata2_3_7_,
        airport5_.icao as icao3_3_7_,
        airport5_.name as name4_3_7_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_new as airline_2_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_old as airline_3_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_new as airplane4_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_old as airplane5_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_new as arrival_6_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_old as arrival_7_10_9_,
        logs6_.comment as comment8_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_new as departur9_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_old as departu10_10_9_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_new as flightn11_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_old as flightn12_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_new as from_ne13_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_old as from_ol14_10_9_,
        logs6_.log_date as log_dat15_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_new as to_new16_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_old as to_old17_10_9_,
        logs6_.user as user18_10_9_,
        flightsche7_.flightno as flightno1_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.airline_id as airline11_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.arrival as arrival2_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.departure as departur3_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.friday as friday4_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.from as from12_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.monday as monday5_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.saturday as saturday6_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.sunday as sunday7_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.thursday as thursday8_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.to as to13_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.tuesday as tuesday9_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.wednesday as wednesd10_11_10_,
        airport8_.airport_id as airport_1_3_11_,
        airport8_.iata as iata2_3_11_,
        airport8_.icao as icao3_3_11_,
        airport8_.name as name4_3_11_ 
    from
        airplane airplane0_ 
    left outer join
        airplane_type airplanety1_ 
            on airplane0_.type_id=airplanety1_.type_id 
    left outer join
        flight flights2_ 
            on airplane0_.airplane_id=flights2_.airplane_id 
    left outer join
        airline airline3_ 
            on flights2_.airline_id=airline3_.airline_id 
    left outer join
        booking bookings4_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=bookings4_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        airport airport5_ 
            on flights2_.from=airport5_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        flight_log logs6_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=logs6_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        flightschedule flightsche7_ 
            on flights2_.flightno=flightsche7_.flightno 
    left outer join
        airport airport8_ 
            on flights2_.to=airport8_.airport_id 
    where
        airplane0_.airplane_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airline0_.airline_id as airline_1_0_0_,
        airline0_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_0_,
        airline0_.base_airport as base_air4_0_0_,
        airline0_.iata as iata3_0_0_,
        airport1_.airport_id as airport_1_3_1_,
        airport1_.iata as iata2_3_1_,
        airport1_.icao as icao3_3_1_,
        airport1_.name as name4_3_1_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_2_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.city as city2_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.country as country3_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.geolocation as geolocat4_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.latitude as latitude5_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.longitude as longitud6_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.name as name7_4_3_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_4_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_5_,
        airportrea3_.hops as hops2_5_5_ 
    from
        airline airline0_ 
    left outer join
        airport airport1_ 
            on airline0_.base_airport=airport1_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_geo airportgeo2_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportgeo2_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_reachable airportrea3_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportrea3_.airport_id 
    where
        airline0_.airline_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airplane0_.airplane_id as airplane1_1_0_,
        airplane0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_0_,
        airplane0_.type_id as type_id4_1_0_,
        airplane0_.capacity as capacity3_1_0_,
        airplanety1_.type_id as type_id1_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.description as descript2_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.identifier as identifi3_2_1_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flights2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flights2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flights2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flights2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flights2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flights2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        airline3_.airline_id as airline_1_0_4_,
        airline3_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_4_,
        airline3_.base_airport as base_air4_0_4_,
        airline3_.iata as iata3_0_4_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_6_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_6_,
        bookings4_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_6_,
        bookings4_.price as price2_7_6_,
        bookings4_.seat as seat3_7_6_,
        airport5_.airport_id as airport_1_3_7_,
        airport5_.iata as iata2_3_7_,
        airport5_.icao as icao3_3_7_,
        airport5_.name as name4_3_7_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_new as airline_2_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_old as airline_3_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_new as airplane4_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_old as airplane5_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_new as arrival_6_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_old as arrival_7_10_9_,
        logs6_.comment as comment8_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_new as departur9_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_old as departu10_10_9_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_new as flightn11_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_old as flightn12_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_new as from_ne13_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_old as from_ol14_10_9_,
        logs6_.log_date as log_dat15_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_new as to_new16_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_old as to_old17_10_9_,
        logs6_.user as user18_10_9_,
        flightsche7_.flightno as flightno1_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.airline_id as airline11_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.arrival as arrival2_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.departure as departur3_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.friday as friday4_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.from as from12_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.monday as monday5_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.saturday as saturday6_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.sunday as sunday7_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.thursday as thursday8_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.to as to13_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.tuesday as tuesday9_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.wednesday as wednesd10_11_10_,
        airport8_.airport_id as airport_1_3_11_,
        airport8_.iata as iata2_3_11_,
        airport8_.icao as icao3_3_11_,
        airport8_.name as name4_3_11_ 
    from
        airplane airplane0_ 
    left outer join
        airplane_type airplanety1_ 
            on airplane0_.type_id=airplanety1_.type_id 
    left outer join
        flight flights2_ 
            on airplane0_.airplane_id=flights2_.airplane_id 
    left outer join
        airline airline3_ 
            on flights2_.airline_id=airline3_.airline_id 
    left outer join
        booking bookings4_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=bookings4_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        airport airport5_ 
            on flights2_.from=airport5_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        flight_log logs6_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=logs6_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        flightschedule flightsche7_ 
            on flights2_.flightno=flightsche7_.flightno 
    left outer join
        airport airport8_ 
            on flights2_.to=airport8_.airport_id 
    where
        airplane0_.airplane_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        passenger0_.passenger_id as passenge1_13_0_,
        passenger0_.firstname as firstnam2_13_0_,
        passenger0_.lastname as lastname3_13_0_,
        passenger0_.passportno as passport4_13_0_,
        bookings1_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_1_,
        bookings1_.booking_id as booking_1_7_1_,
        bookings1_.booking_id as booking_1_7_2_,
        bookings1_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_2_,
        bookings1_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_2_,
        bookings1_.price as price2_7_2_,
        bookings1_.seat as seat3_7_2_,
        flight2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flight2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flight2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flight2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flight2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flight2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flight2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flight2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        passengerd3_.passenger_id as passenge1_14_4_,
        passengerd3_.passenger_id as passenge1_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.birthdate as birthdat2_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.city as city3_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.country as country4_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.emailaddress as emailadd5_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.gender as gender6_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.street as street7_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.telephoneno as telephon8_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.zip as zip9_14_5_ 
    from
        passenger passenger0_ 
    left outer join
        booking bookings1_ 
            on passenger0_.passenger_id=bookings1_.passenger_id 
    left outer join
        flight flight2_ 
            on bookings1_.flight_id=flight2_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        passengerdetails passengerd3_ 
            on passenger0_.passenger_id=passengerd3_.passenger_id 
    where
        passenger0_.passenger_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airline0_.airline_id as airline_1_0_0_,
        airline0_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_0_,
        airline0_.base_airport as base_air4_0_0_,
        airline0_.iata as iata3_0_0_,
        airport1_.airport_id as airport_1_3_1_,
        airport1_.iata as iata2_3_1_,
        airport1_.icao as icao3_3_1_,
        airport1_.name as name4_3_1_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_2_,
        airportgeo2_.airport_id as airport_1_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.city as city2_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.country as country3_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.geolocation as geolocat4_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.latitude as latitude5_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.longitude as longitud6_4_3_,
        airportgeo2_.name as name7_4_3_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_4_,
        airportrea3_.airport_id as airport_1_5_5_,
        airportrea3_.hops as hops2_5_5_ 
    from
        airline airline0_ 
    left outer join
        airport airport1_ 
            on airline0_.base_airport=airport1_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_geo airportgeo2_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportgeo2_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        airport_reachable airportrea3_ 
            on airport1_.airport_id=airportrea3_.airport_id 
    where
        airline0_.airline_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airplane0_.airplane_id as airplane1_1_0_,
        airplane0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_0_,
        airplane0_.type_id as type_id4_1_0_,
        airplane0_.capacity as capacity3_1_0_,
        airplanety1_.type_id as type_id1_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.description as descript2_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.identifier as identifi3_2_1_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flights2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flights2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flights2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flights2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flights2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flights2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        airline3_.airline_id as airline_1_0_4_,
        airline3_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_4_,
        airline3_.base_airport as base_air4_0_4_,
        airline3_.iata as iata3_0_4_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_6_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_6_,
        bookings4_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_6_,
        bookings4_.price as price2_7_6_,
        bookings4_.seat as seat3_7_6_,
        airport5_.airport_id as airport_1_3_7_,
        airport5_.iata as iata2_3_7_,
        airport5_.icao as icao3_3_7_,
        airport5_.name as name4_3_7_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_new as airline_2_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_old as airline_3_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_new as airplane4_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_old as airplane5_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_new as arrival_6_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_old as arrival_7_10_9_,
        logs6_.comment as comment8_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_new as departur9_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_old as departu10_10_9_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_new as flightn11_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_old as flightn12_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_new as from_ne13_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_old as from_ol14_10_9_,
        logs6_.log_date as log_dat15_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_new as to_new16_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_old as to_old17_10_9_,
        logs6_.user as user18_10_9_,
        flightsche7_.flightno as flightno1_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.airline_id as airline11_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.arrival as arrival2_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.departure as departur3_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.friday as friday4_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.from as from12_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.monday as monday5_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.saturday as saturday6_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.sunday as sunday7_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.thursday as thursday8_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.to as to13_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.tuesday as tuesday9_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.wednesday as wednesd10_11_10_,
        airport8_.airport_id as airport_1_3_11_,
        airport8_.iata as iata2_3_11_,
        airport8_.icao as icao3_3_11_,
        airport8_.name as name4_3_11_ 
    from
        airplane airplane0_ 
    left outer join
        airplane_type airplanety1_ 
            on airplane0_.type_id=airplanety1_.type_id 
    left outer join
        flight flights2_ 
            on airplane0_.airplane_id=flights2_.airplane_id 
    left outer join
        airline airline3_ 
            on flights2_.airline_id=airline3_.airline_id 
    left outer join
        booking bookings4_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=bookings4_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        airport airport5_ 
            on flights2_.from=airport5_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        flight_log logs6_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=logs6_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        flightschedule flightsche7_ 
            on flights2_.flightno=flightsche7_.flightno 
    left outer join
        airport airport8_ 
            on flights2_.to=airport8_.airport_id 
    where
        airplane0_.airplane_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        passenger0_.passenger_id as passenge1_13_0_,
        passenger0_.firstname as firstnam2_13_0_,
        passenger0_.lastname as lastname3_13_0_,
        passenger0_.passportno as passport4_13_0_,
        bookings1_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_1_,
        bookings1_.booking_id as booking_1_7_1_,
        bookings1_.booking_id as booking_1_7_2_,
        bookings1_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_2_,
        bookings1_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_2_,
        bookings1_.price as price2_7_2_,
        bookings1_.seat as seat3_7_2_,
        flight2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flight2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flight2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flight2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flight2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flight2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flight2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flight2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        passengerd3_.passenger_id as passenge1_14_4_,
        passengerd3_.passenger_id as passenge1_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.birthdate as birthdat2_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.city as city3_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.country as country4_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.emailaddress as emailadd5_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.gender as gender6_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.street as street7_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.telephoneno as telephon8_14_5_,
        passengerd3_.zip as zip9_14_5_ 
    from
        passenger passenger0_ 
    left outer join
        booking bookings1_ 
            on passenger0_.passenger_id=bookings1_.passenger_id 
    left outer join
        flight flight2_ 
            on bookings1_.flight_id=flight2_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        passengerdetails passengerd3_ 
            on passenger0_.passenger_id=passengerd3_.passenger_id 
    where
        passenger0_.passenger_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        airplane0_.airplane_id as airplane1_1_0_,
        airplane0_.airline_id as airline_2_1_0_,
        airplane0_.type_id as type_id4_1_0_,
        airplane0_.capacity as capacity3_1_0_,
        airplanety1_.type_id as type_id1_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.description as descript2_2_1_,
        airplanety1_.identifier as identifi3_2_1_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_2_,
        flights2_.flight_id as flight_i1_9_3_,
        flights2_.airline_id as airline_4_9_3_,
        flights2_.airplane_id as airplane5_9_3_,
        flights2_.arrival as arrival2_9_3_,
        flights2_.departure as departur3_9_3_,
        flights2_.from as from6_9_3_,
        flights2_.flightno as flightno7_9_3_,
        flights2_.to as to8_9_3_,
        airline3_.airline_id as airline_1_0_4_,
        airline3_.airlinename as airlinen2_0_4_,
        airline3_.base_airport as base_air4_0_4_,
        airline3_.iata as iata3_0_4_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_5_,
        bookings4_.booking_id as booking_1_7_6_,
        bookings4_.flight_id as flight_i4_7_6_,
        bookings4_.passenger_id as passenge5_7_6_,
        bookings4_.price as price2_7_6_,
        bookings4_.seat as seat3_7_6_,
        airport5_.airport_id as airport_1_3_7_,
        airport5_.iata as iata2_3_7_,
        airport5_.icao as icao3_3_7_,
        airport5_.name as name4_3_7_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_8_,
        logs6_.flight_log_id as flight_l1_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_new as airline_2_10_9_,
        logs6_.airline_id_old as airline_3_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_new as airplane4_10_9_,
        logs6_.airplane_id_old as airplane5_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_new as arrival_6_10_9_,
        logs6_.arrival_old as arrival_7_10_9_,
        logs6_.comment as comment8_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_new as departur9_10_9_,
        logs6_.departure_old as departu10_10_9_,
        logs6_.flight_id as flight_19_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_new as flightn11_10_9_,
        logs6_.flightno_old as flightn12_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_new as from_ne13_10_9_,
        logs6_.from_old as from_ol14_10_9_,
        logs6_.log_date as log_dat15_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_new as to_new16_10_9_,
        logs6_.to_old as to_old17_10_9_,
        logs6_.user as user18_10_9_,
        flightsche7_.flightno as flightno1_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.airline_id as airline11_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.arrival as arrival2_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.departure as departur3_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.friday as friday4_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.from as from12_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.monday as monday5_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.saturday as saturday6_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.sunday as sunday7_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.thursday as thursday8_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.to as to13_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.tuesday as tuesday9_11_10_,
        flightsche7_.wednesday as wednesd10_11_10_,
        airport8_.airport_id as airport_1_3_11_,
        airport8_.iata as iata2_3_11_,
        airport8_.icao as icao3_3_11_,
        airport8_.name as name4_3_11_ 
    from
        airplane airplane0_ 
    left outer join
        airplane_type airplanety1_ 
            on airplane0_.type_id=airplanety1_.type_id 
    left outer join
        flight flights2_ 
            on airplane0_.airplane_id=flights2_.airplane_id 
    left outer join
        airline airline3_ 
            on flights2_.airline_id=airline3_.airline_id 
    left outer join
        booking bookings4_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=bookings4_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        airport airport5_ 
            on flights2_.from=airport5_.airport_id 
    left outer join
        flight_log logs6_ 
            on flights2_.flight_id=logs6_.flight_id 
    left outer join
        flightschedule flightsche7_ 
            on flights2_.flightno=flightsche7_.flightno 
    left outer join
        airport airport8_ 
            on flights2_.to=airport8_.airport_id 
    where
        airplane0_.airplane_id=?
```

Comment: As you can see, `Flight` table has a number of relationships to other tables/entities. That's the reason for all the joins (fetches all the entities and their related objects) - To prevent it for a simple query, you indicate in your configuration to not load them at first but to lazy load them (i.e. only when needed) - If you check their documentation, (or a tutorial) you'll see how to configure it

Comment: @blurfus Thank you, but I don't understand the reason for all these joins. I counted the number of connections between the tables to 16, so we should have 16 joins in total, but this is much more.

Comment: Because your mapping is poorly set up. Without knowing the exact mapping it is hard to tell where you went wrong, except for lazy/eager loading

Comment: Can you edit your post to add `Flight` hibernate mapping ? You probably had transitive EAGER relations.

Comment: @Thomas I added a link for models classes with hibernate mappings

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  I added a link for models classes with hibernate mappings

Comment: Please show the code that is using this. That being said all relations will be loaded (if not defined as lazy). With your current setup it will probably do a lot of additional selects, and if you done it really  bad it will also select related data for the relations. The problem you have is that you think that `select f From Flight f` is a SQL query which is not it is a JPQL which eventually will lead to SQL but based on the mapping that you created in your entities. In short with your "simple" select statement it will pobably try to load the whole database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined in your model only EAGER relations, these relations will always be join and fetch.
You should set `EAGER` fetch type only when the relation is required and try to maximise `LAZY` relations.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

```java
public class Flight extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "flight_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int flightId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "from")
    private Airport fromAirport;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "to")
    private Airport toAirport;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "flightno", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private FlightSchedule schedule;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "airline_id")
    private Airline airline;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "airplane_id")
    private Airplane airplane;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FlightLog> logs = new HashSet<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Booking> bookings = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`select f from Flight` will fetch Flight, Flight.Airport (EAGER), Flight.Airport.AirportGeo (EAGER), etc